# How to use group_by date with datetime element to display on calendar by day?

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, hashtable

I'm using a datetime element on my model but for some reason I can't get it to show up in my calendar. I'm using code in the controller and view to do this, the CSS is irrelevant I think so I wont include that. I'm also using a hash to do it.

Events Controller:

```
  def calendarpage
    @events = Event.all
    @events_by_date = @events.group_by(&:edate)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
  end
```

CalendarPageView:

```
<h1>My Calendar</h1>
<div id="events">
<h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", date: @date.prev_month %>
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", date: @date.next_month %>
</h2>
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  <% if @events_by_date[date] %><!-- is this even populated?? -->
    <ul>
        <% @events_by_date[date].each do |event| %>
            <li><%= link_to event.title, event%></li> <!-- THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T SHOW -->
        <% end %>
    </ul>   
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the relevant database entries:
table: events

```
id  title   ... edate
"1" "Test"  ... "2014-10-06 20:38:00.000000"
"2" "t2"    ... "2014-10-07 20:40:00.000000"
```

This might also be useful, though I don't think so: 
Calendar Helper.rb

```
module CalendarHelper
    def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
        Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
    end

    class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
        HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
        START_DAY = :sunday

        delegate :content_tag, to: :view

        def table 
            content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do 
                header + week_rows              
            end
        end

        def header
            content_tag :tr do
                HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
            end
        end

        def week_rows
            weeks.map do |week|
                content_tag :tr do
                    week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
                end
            end.join.html_safe
        end

        def day_cell(day)
            content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
        end

        def day_classes(day)
            classes = []
            classes << "today" if day == Date.today
            classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
            classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
        end

        def weeks
            first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
            last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
            (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
        end
    end
end
```

the calendar displays just fine, and I know that the controller code does get called. But none of the events actually get displayed at all. the 6th and the 7th don't get displayed.

Now, Here's what I'm thinking. I followed a tutorial to make this and I'm thinking that in the tutorial the edate element is a :date element not a :datetime element like I have it, would that make a difference? if so how do I correct for difference in variable type (the extra time info)? if this is the problem do I have to change the Group_by line in the event controller?

One other observation I have is that I appended this code onto the bottom of the view page:

```
<% @events_by_date["7"].each do |event| %>
    <li><%= link_to event.title, event%></li>
<% end %>
```

and I got an error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

This may be because I don't understand how Hashtables work, but something is telling me the @events_by_date isn't being populated in the controller :(

what do I do?